# Create a shortcode to show product tag name on tag archive

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm trying to build a global description for my product tags.
So they will have a general description with shortcodes on it showing the exact tag name.

For example: Buy [tag_name] products

I'm trying to get the tag name and create the shortcode by this code:

```
function displayMotorcycleName($item) {
    $productTag = get_the_terms( get_the_ID(), 'product_tag' );
    return $productTag;
}

add_shortcode('product_tags', 'displayMotorcycleName');
```

However it's showing the word "Array" instead of the tag name.

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Felipe.  You should check here to see how to use get_the_terms.  It does return an array and you will likely want to loop through each of the results. https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_terms/

Answer (score 2):

Because the return value from get_the_terms() is an array, not a string. See the Codex https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_post_terms for the array values returned.

To return the 'name' element of the array , use

```
return $productTag['name'];
```

(The Codex is a great place to figure out what a function does....)